How different can the number of 1s in the inverse be?
If $M$ is a full rank $n$ by $n$ binary matrix over $\mathbb{F}_2$, how much larger or smaller can the number of $1$s in $M^{-1}$ be?
Clearly the identity matrix is an example where the number of ones doesn’t change at all.
This is a question just for mathematical interest. I am trying to understand the properties of matrices over $\mathbb{F}_2$.
Examples
For n=6 there are 251610 inequivalent binary matrices (up to row and column permutations).  Taking only the full rank matrices from this set, these are the max differences in the number of ones between a matrix and its inverse. The first number is the number of ones in the matrix and the second is the max difference for matrices with that number of ones.
6 0
7 0
8 1
9 3
10 6
11 10
12 9
13 16
14 10
15 16
16 10
17 12
18 9
19 9
20 9
21 10
22 9
23 10
24 11
25 12
26 13
27 14
28 15
29 16
30 15
31 16

Cross-posted to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/481762/bounds-for-the-difference-in-the-number-of-ones-in-m-and-m-1

Hi! To avoid down-votes and close-votes, please provide us some context for this question, such as: (a) Is this homework? (b) If so, what course are you taking? (c) What specific topic are you covering at the moment? (d) What do you know that you think might be connected? (e) If you're stuck, what are you stuck on? For example, do you know what to apply, but don't know how to apply it, or do you not know what to apply? Please [edit] these facts into your original post, not as responses to this comment, as comments may be deleted without warning.

The number of entries equal to $1$ can be quite different. Let me just give an example. The following matrix $A\in GL_5(\Bbb F_2)$ has $18$ entries equal to $1$, its inverse only $11$ entries.
$$ 
A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1&0&1&1\cr
1&1&1&0&1\cr
1&0&1&0&0\cr
1&1&1&0&0\cr
1&1&1&1&1 \end{pmatrix},\quad A^{-1}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0&1&0&1\cr
0&0&1&1&0\cr
1&0&0&0&1\cr
0&1&0&0&1\cr
0&1&0&1&0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Do you think there are bounds that can be given?

Yes, there are some conditions known, see for example this post.

That's a bound on the number of ones in a full rank matrix. I was wondering if the number of ones can increase by no more than a constant factor maybe when taking the inverse?

It can increase up to this bound, as examples show, but not more (because the inverse is an invertible matrix itself).

You can't get the maximum number of ones in the inverse of a matrix with n+1 ones I assume...?

I add the data that inspired my question.
